# how to make the gridview to print data from right to left

Tags: asp.net

[gridview image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E21PR.png)
how to make the gridview to print data from right to left , I need column0 to the right and column1 and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can set and bind the column order from your datasource declaratively. for example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Column1" HeaderText="Column1" />
    </Columns>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Column2" HeaderText="Column2" />
    </Columns>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Column3" HeaderText="Column3" />
    </Columns>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Column4" HeaderText="Column4" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Where Column1 is a column in your datasource.

Repeat this for the other columns. The order will be left to right from Top to Bottom. So in this case to have column 2 where column 1 is. make sure the markup for Column 1 comes before column2

Answer (score 0):

Hi I use a printpanel and make it print right to left. 
I put my gridview in a panel tag like this:

```
<asp:Panel id="pnlContents" runat = "server" Direction="RightToLeft">
<asp:GridView ID="G1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  OnRowDataBound="MatchList_RowDataBound" Direction="RightToLeft">
                <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText=" " /> 

                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID" />

                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="first name" DataField="name" />

                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="last name" DataField="family" />

                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="father's name" DataField="father_name" />


            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

</asp:Panel>
```

and I use a button to print the gridview

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print" OnClientClick = "return PrintPanel();" />
```

and this script to print

```js
<script type = "text/javascript">
        function PrintPanel() {
            var panel = document.getElementById("<%=pnlContents.ClientID %>");
            var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
            printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>print preview title</title>');
            printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
            printWindow.document.write(panel.innerHTML);
            printWindow.document.dir = "rtl";
            printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
            printWindow.document.close();
            setTimeout(function () {
                printWindow.print();
            }, 500);
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

***this line makes the print right to left***

```js
printWindow.document.dir = "rtl";
```